# how to sum integer from htmlelement

Tags: javascript, parsefloat

I am trying to get the innerHTML of all elements with classname "money" and sum it. But when I am retrieving it with my code it will place all the digits next to eachother.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("money");
    var arr = new Array(elements.length);
    var total = 0;

    for (var i=0; i< arr.length; i++){
        var val = elements[i].innerHTML;
        console.log(val);
        total += parseFloat(val).toFixed(2)
    }
    console.log(total);
```

The result I'm getting is the following:

[image of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITbUF.png)

How can I solve this?

Comment: **toFixed(2)** will fix your value like 0.00. But **toFixed** return a string. Remove the toFixed and after the for loop just on top of **console.log(total)** add this  **total = total.toFixed(2)**

Answer (score -1):

toFixed() is converting a number to a string. So you add strings which leads to concatenating.

Sum everything and use toFixed() after you have the final value or use Math.round()

Answer (score -2):

[`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) returns a string. Parse it (with a [unary plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus) operator), then add to `total`:

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("money");
var arr = new Array(elements.length);
var total = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var val = elements[i].innerHTML;
  console.log(val);
  total += +parseFloat(val).toFixed(2)
}
console.log(total);
```

```html
<div class="money">100</div>
<div class="money">200</div>
<div class="money">300</div>
```

Comment: so you convert a string to float, add a float and convert it back to string in each iteration of the loop? And you advice the user to buy a faster computer if he complains that the software is so slow? ;)

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff *"And you advice the user to buy a faster computer if he complains that the software is so slow? ;) "* - what are you taking about?